# Rails3 How can I use :params in named scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to display a list of milestones for a particular order. (Orders have many milestones.)

In my orders model, I have this:

```
scope :open, lambda { 
     joins("join milestones on milestones.order_id = orders.id").
      where("order_id = ? AND milestone_status = ?", :params[:order_id], true).
      group("orders.id")
    }
```

The problem I'm having is getting the current order ID to work - :params[:order_id] is clearly wrong.

In my routes I have this:

```
resources :orders do
     resources :milestones
  end
```

And my url is as follows:

http://127.0.0.1/orders/2/milestones

How is this possible? I have tested the scope by replacing with an order ID manually.

-- EDIT --

As per advice below, I've put the following in my milestones controller:

```
@orders = Order.open( params[:order_id] )
```

And in my view, I have this:

<% @orders.each do |open| %>

But I get an error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

The full stacktrace is here: http://pastie.org/2442518

Comment: Will do. Just popped out. Will paste later. Thanks again

Comment: @Mauricio-Linhares. Have edited my answer with the full trace - thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to get with this scope, the milestones of the order `order_id` which have a `true` status? Your intent isn't clear from your question, it would really help to have a better idea of what you're aiming for.

Comment: Did you get it worked at the end? I have the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667615/pass-a-parameter-from-view-to-a-scope-defined-in-the-model

Answer (score 4):

Define it like this:

```
scope :open, lambda { |order_id|
 joins("join milestones on milestones.order_id = orders.id").
  where("order_id = ? AND milestone_status = ?", order_id, true).
  group("orders.id")
}
```

And call it on your controller like this:

```
def index
    @orders = Order.open( params[:order_id] )
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Have put in milestones controller but I get an error. Have updated my question. Jx

Comment: Did you add the `|order_id|` part to the lambda?

Comment: @Eric - yep, followed as above.

Comment: @mauricio-linhares Still can't get the above working. Any chance of some assistance :) jx

Comment: Add the full current source you are using, there is something missing in your code.