# Pass a parameter from view to a scope defined in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im refactoring my code and try to follow the convention "Skinny controllers, fat models"
Now i tried to move a Query to the model:

```
scope :scope1_department, where(sender_username: params[:username], recipient_username: params[:username])
scope :scope2_department, where(recipient_username:  params[:username])
scope_department  = scope1_department.merge(scope2_department).sort_by(&:created_at)
```

And in my controller i have:

```
 @messages = Message.scope_department(params[:username])
```

Now i get this error for my model code:

```
 undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Class:0x85d0b80>
```

I also tried in my model to replace the params[:username] with simply username but then i get the error:

```
 undefined local variable or method `username' for #<Class:0x459fa50>
```

There is a similar question, but how you can se i made something wrong:
[Rails3 How can I use :params in named scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214966/rails3-how-can-i-use-params-in-named-scope)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `params` variable in your model. What you can do is to pass a variable to the scope using a lambda:

```
scope :scope1_department, ->(username){ where(sender_username: username, recipient_username: username)}
```

In your controller:

```
@messages = Message.scope1_department(params[:username])
```

Comment: Somehow in `scope :scope1_department, ->(username){where(sender_username: username, recipient_username: username)}` i get the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` what did i wrong?

Comment: I call it with `@messages = Message.scope_department(params[:username])`

Answer (score 2):

Ways to pass arguments to a scope:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  # a scope using a lambda
  scope :scope2_department, lambda { |name| where(recipient_username: name) }

  # same as above, ruby 1.9+ syntax
  scope :scope3_department, ->(name) { where(recipient_username: name) }

  # a class method
  def self.scope4_department(username)
    where(recipient_username: username)
  end
end
```

Comment: Now i tried `scope :scope1_department, lambda { |username| where(sender_username: username, recipient_username: username)}` But somehow i get the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Comment: Now it works! But i have one more question! You wrote a class method, what is when i have two where defined in it how do i merge them?